# Gradle issue building Android app: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm having an issue building my app for Android with React-Native. I haven't changed much things on my app recently but something seem to have changed suddenly, certainly due to one of my dependency.

When I try to run `assembleRelease` I get the following error:

```
/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/9dc7663ea18f37ca9d48501ef1071cf3/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:5-157: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/9dc7663ea18f37ca9d48501ef1071cf3/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:5-135: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/9dc7663ea18f37ca9d48501ef1071cf3/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jail-monkey:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

However when I run `assembleDebug` everything is going well so I'm not sure what is the issue.

The build runs on a linux Docker image with no cache and which has the latest version of sdk-tools 26.1.1.

From what I've read online, this issue seems to come from appcompat which is not the right version. And the dependency having issue seems to be [jail-monkey](https://github.com/GantMan/jail-monkey) which hasn't received an update for a few months now.

In my build.gradle, this is some of my dependencies:

```
implementation project(':react-native-svg')
implementation project(':react-native-config')
implementation project(':jail-monkey')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```

I've tried to set appcompact-v7 with 23, 26, 27 and 28 in my gradle file, none of them worked. Though during the build it seems to use 26.1 from the dependency.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?